# Get the ExtJS Active Ajax call count

Tags: extjs, selenium

I am working in selenium to test the ExtJs application. My problem is, I need to ensure the page is completely rendered. I cant use selenium.waitForPageLoad. In normal Ajax application i can use "Ajax.activeRequestCount", which will give the Ajax call count. If it is '0' We can ensure the page is completly loaded. Is there any similar function available in ExtJs? Can any one pls help me on this

Comment: You might want to specify exact version of ExtJs you're using

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method in ExtJs. You can however create handlers for global Ext.Ajax events `beforerequest` and `requestcomplete` http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-event-beforerequest and count active connections yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if the Selenium tests are to be run in modern browsers, you could try [Progress Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners) (with [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgressListener)).

For Firefox, you could create a simple addon that would wait for async requests to complete, and ship that addon with your Selenium tests.

Comment: But we need to run the scripts on chrome and IE too

Comment: Then go for @sha's answer. Progress listeners are a new technology, IE has some basic support in IE9 (no support in < IE8), Mozilla started to implement it in FF4 onwards, Chrome can do them for quite some time, too. They are the general solution for this problem, but only in modern browsers, yeah.